# The space $\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

For a open Lipschitz domain $\Omega$, consider the space 
$$A =\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)\}.$$

Now I heard somewhere that all the second derivatives of a function $u$ are controlled by its Laplacian (because $|u|_{L^2} + |\Delta u|_{L^2}$ is equivalent to $|u|_{H^2}$) so then is not $A=H^2(\Omega)$?

Why is this space used??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is convex or smooth, one knows that the solution $v$ of
\begin{align*}-\Delta v + v &= f \quad\text{in }\Omega\\\frac{\partial}{\partial n}v + v &= 0 \quad\text{on }\Gamma\end{align*}
Belongs to $H^2(\Omega)$ for all $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. In this regular case, you get indeed $A = H^2(\Omega)$.

However, this is not the case, e.g., for the L-shaped domain. Then, the solution with $f = 1$ belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$ but not to $H^2(\Omega)$. However, you still have $-\Delta v = f - v \in L^2(\Omega)$.

**Edit:** In the case without boundary conditions,
this is not true. Consider $g \in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \setminus H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$ and let $u$ be the harmonic extension of $g$. Then, you have $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$. However, $u \not\in H^2(\Omega)$, since its trace $g$ does not belong to $H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: In your last sentence, how can you rearrange the equation to give $-\Delta v \in L^2$? because the equation only holds in a weak sense (multiplied by a test function) and not pointwise?

Comment: But the Laplacian is also defined in a weak sense, so it perfectly fits together.

Comment: Hello, I'm wondering if the norms $\|u\|_{H_\Delta(\Omega)} := \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} +\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$  and $\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$ are equivalent ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you have the $H^2$-regularity for the differential equation, you get the equivalence of these norms.

Comment: If the domain is smooth, not necessarily convex, do we have $A=H^{2}(\Omega)$? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this should hold true.

Comment: Dear gerw, I am searching for a reference for this one. Could you help me with one suggestion? (your last statement)

Comment: This is in section 6.3.2 in the PDE book by Evans.

Comment: I don't see how we can claim that $H^{2}(\Omega)=\{u\in H^{1}(\Omega):\Delta u\in L^{2}(\Omega)\}$ (assume $\Omega$ is smooth). In the book by Evans, he needs the assumption that $u\in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. That is if $u\in H^{1}_{0}$ and $\Delta u\in L^{2}$ then $u\in H^{2}$. Note that here we only have $u\in H^{1}$.

Comment: In this case, the regularity of $u$ fails. See my recent edit.

Comment: @gerw How do you know the Harmonic extension always exits? Thanks.

Comment: It is the weak solution of $-\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$ and $u  = g$ on $\partial\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta u\in L^2$ is equivalent to the $H^2$ seminorm in the whole space (you can use Riesz transforms), or in the periodic case (same reason).

However, if you try to obtain the same result in a bounded domain, integrating by parts you get some "extra" terms coming from the boundary. If you impose some boundary conditions (for instance $u,Du=0$) for your functions then you can handle this new terms.

In your set $A$ there is no conditions on the value of the function of its derivatives in the boundary.